# looker Studio Table Data Export not Exporting all rows

Tags: looker-studio, looker

in Looker Studio i have a table that has dynamic number of rows depending on the filter done, the number may vary between 10 to 1000's. Now based on the Report Design i have designed my table to show about 15 records. and page limit set to 500.

So When i Export into excel i get all my Data however when i export the report on PDF in only get the 15 record.

Is there a way to configure looker studio to export the table data dynamically based on the number of rows?

Regards . .

i tried changing the page limit, changed with Pagination settings.

I am expecting the PDF export to extract all rows and fit the the table dynamically.

Comment: PDF printing, prints what is on the page unfortunately. You can hide pages if you wanted to try having pages dedicated just to the table and control the rows shown by row number.